# How to rename PDF in primefaces media tag

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces, pdf-generation, embed

I am using streamedcontent in primefaces and using media tag to show it. When download button is pressed in the viewer it downloads file with the name dynamiccontent.properties. Is there any way to rename it?

> I am using html4, java 7 and primefaces 5.2.24.

I have tried to set parameter #toolbar to hide the toolbar like below but it is not working:

```
<p:media id="pdfViewer" value="#{mybean.pdfMedia}" width="100%" height="90%" player="pdf" cache="false" >
        <f:param name="#toolbar" value="0"></f:param>
</p:media>
```

and my streamed content is generating from iText like this:

```
   baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   document = new Document();
   document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
   document.setMargins(70, 70, 100, 100);
   writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
   document.open();
   document.newPage();
   XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(pageContents));
   document.close();

   InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
   StreamedContent  pdfMedia = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Is there any way to rename the it? or is there any way to hide the tool bar?

Comment: Please show the code where you create the StreamedContent instance.

Comment: @Selaron updated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393132/default-header-pmedia-with-pdf-player

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in PF 5.2.24 that you are using and is fixed in PF 6.1 or higher.
See this bug ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2055

Make sure to set "NAME" in the DefaultStreamedContent by either using the constructor `org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent.DefaultStreamedContent(InputStream stream, String contentType, String name)` or the `org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent.setName(String)` method.

Comment: this error is happening again in PF 10.0,   despite i set the name in the DefaultStreamContent

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a Name for your streamed content by either using the constructor 
`org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent.DefaultStreamedContent(InputStream stream, String contentType, String name)` or the `org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent.setName(String)` method.

Comment: the name remains the same . i.e. dynamiccontent.properties.jsf

Comment: I think Chrome has locked down this behavior for PDF's.