# Primefaces embedded PDF media shows as "dynamiccontent.properties.jsf" in Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

I have a very similar problem to
[How to rename PDF in primefaces media tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865134/how-to-rename-pdf-in-primefaces-media-tag)

However, I'm using Primefaces 7.0 so it can't be the bug that got fixed with 6.1, nor am I forgetting to set the name by myself. I've read about Chrome having changed something (deliberately or not) so that we can't set the displayed name anymore. Anyone having more infos or some workaround?

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

The use of `p:media` for PDF's has been a hack over the years and the browser keep changing. That filename trick for PDF's use to work then it stopped working when Chrome made some changes.

See this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5901

PrimeFaces has deprecated use of PDF in Media for 11.0. If you really want to render PDF's and be able to download with a proper name I suggest checking out PrimeFaces Extensions DocumentViewer: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf

However Chrome 92 recently made a change that broke it we had to fix you can read about here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/122

Comment: I am currently experiencing this problem, but I just noticed something: if the PDF document has a "_document title_" set in its metadata properties, that value will appear at the top of the viewer. If the title is not set in the properties of the PDF file, the text "_dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml_" appears.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation about the pdf player being deprecated in [PrimeFaces 11](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/media) as of July, 2022.

Comment: Its not but see this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2055  Chrome and other browsers no longer support setting the "title".